# How can I allow only the dictionary keys "source", "dest" and "keep" (see: config.json below) as dictionary keys in json schema?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, schema, jsonschema

How can I allow only the dictionary keys "source", "dest" and "keep" (see: config.json below) as dictionary keys in json schema?

Using `"required": ["snapshots"]` together with `"additionalProperties": False` I managed to allow only the key "snapshots", but doing that analogous for the dictionary value of the key "string" (`"required": ["source","dest", "keep"]`)  didn't add the desired constraints to my json config.

I tested latter, by changing e.g. the key "source" to "somethingElse" in my `config.json` file, but `jsonschema.validate()` didn't raise any errors, though I expected it to.

schemaTest.py:

```
import json
from jsonschema import validate

schema = {
             "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
             "required": ["snapshots"],
             "additionalProperties": False,
             "properties":
             {
                 "snapshots":
                 {
                     "type": "object",
                     "properties":
                     {
                         "string":
                         {
                             "type": "object",
                             "items": { "type": "string" },
                             "uniqueItems": True,
                             "properties":
                             {
                                 "source": {"type": "string"},
                                 "dest": {"type": "string"},
                                 "keep": {"type": "string"}
                             },
                             "required": ["source","dest", "keep"],
                             "additionalProperties": False
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

path = "/home/user/test/config.json"
jsonConfig = json.load(open(path))
print(validate(jsonConfig, schema))
```

config.JSON:

```
{
    "snapshots":
    {
        "@snapshot1":
        {
            "source": "/mnt/subvolContainer/@snapshot1",
            "dest": "/mnt/subvolContainer/",
            "keep": "w=10,m=10"
        },
        "@snapshot2":
        {
            "source": "/mnt/subvolContainer/@snapshot2",
            "dest": "/mnt/subvolContainer/",
            "keep": "w=10,m=10"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some extra layers of nesting inside the definition of your snapshot object. `string`, for example, is not a property name you are using. To validate properties of the children of unknown keys in an object, you need to put your types *inside* the `additionalProperties` object. `items` and `uniqueItems` apply to arrays, not objects.

This works:

```
schema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema",
  "required": ["snapshots"],
  "additionalProperties": False,
  "properties":
  {
    "snapshots":
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties":
      {
        "type": "object",
        "properties":
        {
          "source": {"type": "string"},
          "dest": {"type": "string"},
          "keep": {"type": "string"}
        },
        "required": ["source","dest", "keep"],
        "additionalProperties": False
      }
    }
  }
}
```